# Tensorflow, Cannot feed value of shape ..... for Tensor

Tags: tensorflow

I have a problem with linear regression and 3d matrices.
They are all floating point numbers, with labels.

I got started from this code but I changed the matrix: 
https://aqibsaeed.github.io/2016-07-07-TensorflowLR/

With 2 dimensions, it is working well but, with 3, I can not get it running.

this is the shape

```
(387, 7, 10) shape train_x
(387, 1) shape train_x
(43, 7, 10) test_x.shape
(43, 1) test_y.shape
```

```
n_dim = f.shape[1]
train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(f,l,test_size=0.1, shuffle =False)
print(train_x.shape)
print(train_y.shape)
print(test_x.shape)
print(test_y.shape)
learning_rate = 0.01
training_epochs = 1000
cost_history = np.empty(shape=[1],dtype=float)

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,n_dim])
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,1])
W = tf.Variable(tf.ones([n_dim,1]))

#init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

y_ = tf.matmul(X, W)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_ - Y))
training_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)


sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

for epoch in range(training_epochs):
    sess.run(training_step,feed_dict={X:train_x,Y:train_y})
    cost_history = np.append(cost_history,sess.run(cost,feed_dict={X: train_x,Y: train_y}))

    plt.plot(range(len(cost_history)),cost_history)
plt.axis([0,training_epochs,0,np.max(cost_history)])
plt.show()

pred_y = sess.run(y_, feed_dict={X: test_x})
mse = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(pred_y - test_y))
print("MSE: %.4f" % sess.run(mse)) 

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(test_y, pred_y)
ax.plot([test_y.min(), test_y.max()], [test_y.min(), test_y.max()], 'k--', lw=3)
ax.set_xlabel('Measured')
ax.set_ylabel('Predicted')
plt.show()

 </ blink>

this is the mistake




  \session.py", line 1100, in _run
        % (np_val.shape, subfeed_t.name, str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))

    ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (387, 7, 10) for Tensor 'Placeholder_12:0', which has shape '(?, 7)'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error message shows exact reason why it is raised.
The dimension between placeholder and `train_x` doesn't fit.

`train_x` has a (387, 7, 10) shape. In usual convention, you have 387 datapoint which has (7, 10) dimension.

But, `X` (placeholder, the bucket you will put `train_x` in) has a [None, n_dim] (I guess n_dim is 7) shape.

Using [None, ~] in the first element is only accepted as the number of datapoints, not dimension of your data.

So you need to change [None, n_dim] to [None, 7, 10] in this case.

edited)

In this case, `X` is not exacty 3D data. just a bunch of 2D data. For direct weight multiplication of 2D data, you need convolution step. That is CNN. But you only have very small dimension data matrix, you just need to reshape (7,10) matrix shape data to (7*10) vector shape data.

Using `tf.reshape` function.`tf.reshape(X, shape=[387, 7*10])` will be works, and also change your `W` to right dimension to multiply. like, `tf.Variable(tf.ones([7*10,1]))`.

Comment: '''
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None, 7, 10])#<<<<<<<<<<
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,1])
'''

59, in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl
    raise ValueError(err.message)

ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 3 for 'MatMul_8' (op: '

Comment: 9, in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl
    raise ValueError(err.message)

ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 3 for 'MatMul_8' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [?,7,10], [7,1].

Comment: @Roberto you will need a different placeholder for your 2D and 3D matrix. For 2D, use what you had originally, and for 3D use what pjh is suggesting.

Comment: honestly, I did not even think 3d could do it.
I used Weka but the input is 2d
Now, I do not know if the thing has a solution

Comment: maybe it is possible through these functions but it is currently out of my comprehension 
 https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/SparseTensor